# A thought experiment about time dilation

Tags: general-relativity, speed-of-light, time-dilation, thought-experiment

Suppose you are on am infinitely long train traveling on tracks and an atmosphere that has no resistance whatsoever. No this train is traveling at fractionally below the speed of light, and you are on the train traveling fractionally less than the speed of light in the opposite direction that the train is going thus the train experiences time much slower than the outside world, but    you traveling in the opposite direction of the train inside the train experience Time the same as the outside world yet much slower than the train. However this creates a paradox you experience time slower than the train but the same as the outside world, but the train experiences time slower than the outside world and slower than you. My question is how do we solve this paradox to make it true?

Comment: Your confusion is in using different reference frames for comparison. For each of your statements with "experiences", add "in which reference frame", and everything will become clear.

Comment: What does "experience time" mean?

Answer (score 3):

Relstivity doesn't say that time is fastest when you're at rest. It says that a clock appears fastest in a frame at rest with the clock.

Answer (score 0):

All frames of reference are equally valid. If you are inside the train, but running backwards as fast as the train is moving forwards so that you are at rest relative to an outside observer, it will not matter whether you are in the train or outside standing beside the outside observer you will both see the train as moving quickly past, with a slower time frame than yours. An observer in the train, at rest relative to the train could consider the train standing still and you (inside or out) and the outside observer moving quickly past with a slower time frame than his. Both frames of reference are equally valid. Special Theory of Relativity accounts for all this.

Comment: Yet once you stop one object must have aged less than the other. then how do you know which one aged faster and which one slower when everything is moving relative to the other object. what object will time pass relatively slower and which one will time pass relatively faster, when they both are moving relative to eachother?

Comment: stopping and returning to compare clocks involves deceleration and acceleration,  which would slow their time frame as gravity would. this would call for General Theory of Relativity

Comment: @Adrian Howard no it would not.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates

Comment: @m4r35n357 no, what would not?

Comment: stopping and returning to compare clocks involves deceleration and acceleration, which would slow their time frame as gravity would. _would not_ call for General Theory of Relativity

Comment: STR can handle acceleration in flat spacetime. Are you familiar with the relativistic rocket formulae?

Comment: @Adrian Howard the OP did not mention gravity, and neither did your original comment